# xcode xib check if outlets still valid

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

During iOS Development every once in a while, i have to remove a former IBOutlet from a class.
But they ofc don't get removed inside the XIB-Files.
Checking the file reveals exclamation marks, telling you, that the connections aren't valid anymore.

Since my project is quite big, i dont always remember to remove the references from all XIB-Files.
Is there a way to make the compiler check if all the outlets are still valid?

EDIT:
The Build Setting Flags for "Show Errors", "Show Notices" and "Show Warnings" under "Interface Builder XIB Compiler" are set to YES.